# Find given row in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an m by n matrix in `MATLAB`, say M. I have an n-element row vector, i.e. a one by n column matrix, say X.

I know X is a row somewhere in M. How can I find the index in M?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### EDIT:

gnovice's suggestion is even simpler than mine:

```
[~,indx]=ismember(X,M,'rows')

indx =

     3
```

---

#### FIRST SOLUTION:

You can easily do it using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) and [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html). Here's an example:

```
M=magic(4);        %#your matrix

M =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

X=[9 7 6 12];      %#your row vector

find(ismember(M,X),1)

ans =

     3
```

Comment: You could modify your solution slightly using the `'rows'` argument to ISMEMBER to remove the need for FIND: `[~,index] = ismember(X,M,'rows')`

Comment: I think 'rows'keyword is still needed in find(ismember(M,X.'rows'),1)

Comment: ismember is slow. is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 8):

Before I learned of `ismember`, I used to do:

```
index = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, M, X), 2));
```

But using `ismember(X, M, 'rows')` is definitely preferable.

Comment: This is a nice solution since it returns ALL rows of the matrix in which X occurs (unlike the marked answer).

Comment: This solution is far faster than the accepted one (about 20 times on a big scale - tested), and it returns all rows, not just the largest index.

Comment: Interesting. I think I checked for a performance difference before adding this answer and didn't see any, but maybe I didn't use large enough arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that returns a row index for each occurrence of X is

```
find(sum(abs(M-ones(rows(M),1)*X),2)==0)
```

Also, this solution can be easily adapted to find rows that are within threshold of X as follows (if numerical noise is an issue)

```
tolerance = 1e-16; %setting the desired tolerance
find(sum(abs(M-ones(rows(M),1)*X),2)<tolerance)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-loop version. It is only suitable, if M (your matrix) is not very large, ie. n and m are small. X is your row:

```
function ind = findRow(M,X)
    tmp = M - repmat(X,size(M,1),1); 
    ind = find(tmp,1); 
end
```

If M is too large, it might be faster, to iterate the rows of M and compare every row with your vector.

@Edit: renamed variables to match the names used in the question.