# MATLAB find a row of chars in a matrix

Tags: string, matlab, search, find

There is a char matrix. Each row is a word. All the words/rows have the same length.

Is there anyway to find a target word in this matrix using `find()` function?

Say `M=[o k a y; g o o d; h a v e];` A target word `W='have';` Is there any function to search `W` in `M` and return the row index?

When I try `index = find(isequal(W,M))` and `index = find(isequal(W,M(:,:)))`, they both return empty array.

I know that I can use linear search, i.e. to compare row by row, just wonder if there is a built-in function to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find given row in a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209904/find-given-row-in-a-matrix)

Comment: Please accept the most suitable answer by clicking the check-mark on the left hand side of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).  Assuming that `M` is a character array like you have defined, you would thus do:

```
W = 'have';
[~,idx] = ismember(M, W, 'rows');
```

The first input is the character array defined, the second input is the string we are searching for, and we choose `'rows'` as the flag as we want to search on a row basis.  Each word is defined in one row.  The first output is `true/false` that is of the same size as `M` that tells you whether or not we have found the word indexed by that row in `M` is a match to the one you're searching for.  Because we only want to know where that word is, we can suppress that first output. `idx` tells you which **row** the word was found.

When we call this function, we get:

```
idx = 

3
```

This means that the third row contains the word you're looking for.  However, if you're dead set on using `find`, consider using `ismember` in conjunction with `find`:

```
W = 'have';
idx = find(ismember(M, W, 'rows'));

idx = 

3
```

However, the advantage with the above approach is that it will find **all locations** that match the particular word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `M` with a string. I am assuming M contains of individual characters as follows:

```
M=['o' 'k' 'a' 'y'; 'g' 'o' 'o' 'd'; 'h' 'a' 'v' 'e']
```

and `W='have'`

So in order to compare each row of M with W, you need to use `strcmp`. For that, you need `M` to be a cell array. You can convert each row of `M` into a cell array by using `mat2cell`.

```
equalRows=strcmp(W, mat2cell(M,ones(1,size(M,1)),size(M,2)));

% Answer

equalRows =

 0
 0
 1
```

Use `find` command on the above output to get the indices.