# How to find column in matrix which has contents equal to vector

Tags: matlab

I have a n x 1 vector V and a n x d matrix M. I know that V is equivalent to one of the columns of M. How can I find the index of M which corresponds to V? I've tried `ismember` and `find` but I cannot think of the solution.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209904/find-given-row-in-a-matrix) for a couple of alternatives. You can tweak solutions to fit your needs :)

Comment: How have you tried `ismember`? You could use the `'rows'` flag and transpose...

Comment: I saw the answer you posted Benoit, but it only does rows; I now see the logic behind all of your suggestions and it works :)

Comment: @user2680312 anything that only works on rows can be adapted to work on columns instead by simply transposing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ismember` allows looking for 1-by-d vectors in a nxd matrix. All we need to do to make it work for your problem is transposing arrays:

```
[~, columnIdx] = ismember( nByOneVector.', nByDMatrix.', 'rows');
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `ismember` is using `bsxfun`:

```
find(all(bsxfun(@eq, V, M)))
```

Here `bsxfun` applies the `@eq` operation (i.e. `==`) to `V` and every column of `M`. We then use `all` to make sure that the entire column matched and finally `find` to convert from the logical vector to the column index.